# js label "Range" при прокрутки любого изменяет чего то только последний

Tags: javascript

js при изменении слайдера любого изменяет только последний Как исправить?

```
<div class="price">
            <form action="">
                <label for="Range">Min price:</label> <span id="demo"></span> USD</p>
                <input type="range" min="100" max="1000" value1="500" id="Range">

                <label for="Range1">Max price:</label> <span id="demo1"></span> USD</p>
                <input type="range" min="1000" max="2000" value2="1500" id="Range1">

                <label for="Range2">Min RAM:</label> <span id="demo2"></span> USD</p>
                <input type="range" min=2 max="16" value="8" id="Range2">
                <label for="Range3">Max RAM:</label> <span id="demo3"></span> GB</p>
                <input type="range" min="8" max="64" value="32" id="Range3">
            </form>
        </div>


var slider = document.getElementById("Range");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function () {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        var slider = document.getElementById("Range1");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo1");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function () {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        var slider = document.getElementById("Range2");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo2");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function () {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        var slider = document.getElementById("Range3");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo3");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function () {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var price = document.querySelector(".price");

price.oninput = fOnInput;

function fOnInput() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Range").value;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Range1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Range2").value;
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Range3").value;
}

fOnInput();
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <form action="">
    <p><label for="Range">Min price:</label> <span id="demo"></span> USD</p>
    <input type="range" min="100" max="1000" value1="500" id="Range">

    <p><label for="Range1">Max price:</label> <span id="demo1"></span> USD</p>
    <input type="range" min="1000" max="2000" value2="1500" id="Range1">

    <p><label for="Range2">Min RAM:</label> <span id="demo2"></span> USD</p>
    <input type="range" min=2 max="16" value="8" id="Range2">

    <p><label for="Range3">Max RAM:</label> <span id="demo3"></span> GB</p>
    <input type="range" min="8" max="64" value="32" id="Range3">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: чего то не показывает стандартных значений, только появляются когда начинаешь изменять

Comment: @recile поправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое